# ffmpeg showwaves - Change color of waveform on top of an image

Tags: ffmpeg

I need help with ffmpeg.

I wrote this code:

```
@echo off  
for %%F in (*.opus *.ogg) do 
(  
  ffmpeg -y -i "%%F" -loop 1 -i "default.jpg" -filter_complex " 
 [0:a]showwaves=s=2560x1440:mode=cline:r=30,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];
[1:v][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -speed 8 -acodec copy -shortest "%%~nF.webm" 
)
```

What it does is that for each .opus or .ogg audio file, it'll output a video with a default.jpg background image (which is completely white) and a waveform on top of it, with the audio playing.
Problem is, I would change the color of the waveform to black, but I don't understand how colorkey works even after reading the documentation...

Basically, I want to obtain something like this (but the waveform being in black): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9arneFijG8

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `colors` option in the [showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.opus -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i default.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=2560x1440:mode=cline:r=30:colors=black[v];[1:v][v]overlay=format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a copy -shortest output.webm
```

Alternatively, since you said `default.jpg` is completely white you can just make ffmpeg generate the white background instead with the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) source filter:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.opus -f lavfi -i color=size=2560x1440:rate=30:color=white -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=size=2560x1440:mode=cline:rate=30:colors=black[v];[1:v][v]overlay=format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a copy -shortest output.webm
```

- `color=size=2560x1440:rate=30:color=white` make a white background that is 2560x1440 with a frame rate of 30.
- `aformat=channel_layouts=mono` make the audio mono with [aformat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) filter before giving it to showwaves so there is one combined waveform instead of one waveform per channel. This won't affect the audio that will be put in the output file.
- `[1:v][v]overlay=format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2` is the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter. It will use `-i color` (`[1:v]`) as background and foreground is the output from the aformat + showwaves *filterchain* (a collective name for a linear set of filters connected via commas) named `[v]`. You can name it anything if you don't like `[v]`. The `format` overlay option will choose the best looking colorspace, `x=(W-w)/2` centers on x axis, `y=(H-h)/2` centers on y axis.
- `format=yuv420p` is the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter and makes the output from the *filtergraph* (a collective name for **all** of the filters) be yuv420p pixel format for playback compatibility reasons. Although it has the same name this is a **filter** and is different than the `format` **option** in the overlay filter.
- `[outv]` is the arbitrary name I gave the final output from all of the filters.
- `-map "[outv]" -map 0:a` tells ffmpeg to only include the filter output and the audio from `input.opus` into the output file.

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked perfectly :) Do you happen to know how to make it looks like the one from the video? I mean not about the color but the visualization in itself.

Comment: @GrantSYNKOP No. You would have to use some other tool to get that look.

Comment: Right, I understand it's not the purpose of ffmpeg. Thank you again! It was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks llogan! Can you teach us how the configure a ffmpeg command. For example what this means: format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a

Comment: Wooww llogan! Thanks so much for spending some of your time teaching us!